# Menu items in Orchard (duplicate items not shown)

Tags: menu, orchardcms

I have a site in orchard where the same page should appear multiple time in navigation tree (menu).

I have created several items pointing to the same Content Item and named in the same way.
Now only the first one is actually shown.

To display the second and the third I have to rename it in a different way.

It seems that if I have two menu items that display the same text just the first item is shown.

Any other has the same problem?

Have you found a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is this bug: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19205, fixed last December. Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks... I'm just curious about this: "We still want to remove duplicates under a given parent, but not in the menu as a whole."
Why do you want this? If I put 2 menus with same text on same menu it is my fault or my reason... why did you need to "correct" this in code?